# Log4j2 programmatic configuration for a webapp

Tags: java, web-applications, log4j2

I am trying to setup a configurable log4j configuration path for our webapp, so that by default this setting applies:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfiguration</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/log4j2.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

and if, lets say, some environment variable is defined, then log4j2-test.xml is used. Can I somehow achieve this?
I've tried defining my own listener, which will take care of this, as follows:
web.xml contents:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfiguration</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/log4j2.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>isLog4jAutoInitializationDisabled</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>com.bla.blob.listener.Log4j2InitListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

And the listener class:

```
public class Log4j2InitListener implements ServletContextListener {

  @Override
  public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
    ServletContext ctx = sce.getServletContext();
    if (System.getProperty("log4j.configurationFile") != null) { //override what is defined in web.xml
  ctx.setInitParameter("log4jConfiguration", System.getProperty("log4j.configurationFile"));
}
ctx.addListener(new Log4jServletContextListener());

final FilterRegistration.Dynamic filter = ctx.addFilter("log4jServletFilter", 
    new Log4jServletFilter());
if (filter != null) {
  filter.setAsyncSupported(true);
  filter.addMappingForUrlPatterns(EnumSet.allOf(DispatcherType.class), false, "/*");
}
  }

  @Override
  public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) { }
}
```

But for some strange reason this solution is not tomcat compatible (though works on jetty) -

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Once the first ServletContextListener has been called, no more ServletContextListeners may be added.
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.addListener(ApplicationContext.java:1386)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContextFacade.addListener(ApplicationContextFacade.java:659)
```

Also, apache moved everything webapp related out of core, making everything package private, so you can't fiddle with classes by yourself anymore (yet http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/webapp.html still suggest you can use Log4jWebLifeCycle, for instance).
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is your Tomcat version ? And why do you manually add Log4jServletContextListener in you code ?

Comment: Tomcat version is 7.0.55.
I manually configure Log4jServlet to be able to override log4jConfiguration context-param BEFORE log4j configures itself.